# Copy Security information

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Using C/C++ on Win32, I'm creating a new file `A` but I want to copy the exact security information from an old file `B`.  By security information, I mean groups/names and corresponding permissions. For example:

[image: Security Information (screenshot)]

What kind of [`SECURITY_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecAuthZ/security-information) do I need to copy?

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  They are distinct languages.  For example, C++ has `std::string` and `std::transform`.  In C, you can have a variable or function called `class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GetNamedSecurityInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-getnamedsecurityinfoa)() to get all information you need like owner/group and access control(DACL/SACL) from the old file then Creating a Security Descriptor using information you've got and set the security descriptor when you create a new file ([CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea)()).

There are "[Modifying the ACLs of an Object in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecAuthZ/modifying-the-acls-of-an-object-in-c--)" and "[Creating a Security Descriptor for a New Object in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecAuthZ/creating-a-security-descriptor-for-a-new-object-in-c--)" you can refer to.